# UIB Popover Moving and Rearranging on Click

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've implemented a UI-Bootstrap popover to allow the user to select a mathematical operator in my app. My issue is that the popover appears in the wrong place, moves on click, and changes its arrangement of the buttons. My understanding of the issue is that it might be caused by variable sizing and placement of spans (which I use for the buttons) but I haven't been able to get it working properly.

When the operator symbol is first clicked:
[image]

When you choose a new operator:
[image]

When you choose another operator:
[image: (this is the correct position for the popover, centered over the button)]

When you close the popover and then open it again:
[image]

Here's my code for the popover and the buttons:

In index.jade:

```
button.btn.btn-default(type = "button", uib-popover-template="operatorsPopover.templateUrl", popover-title="{{operatorsPopover.title}}", popover-trigger="'outsideClick'", popover-placement="top")
    span(class="{{splitStruct.operator}}") // this is the button you click to open the popover

script(type='text/ng-template', id='operatorsPopoverTemplate.html')
    button(type = "button", ng-repeat='operator in operatorsPopover.operators', ng-click="splitStruct.operator = operator")
        span.popover_button(class = "{{operator}}", size="24")
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.operatorsPopover = {
        title: "Operator",
        templateUrl: 'operatorsPopoverTemplate.html',
        operators: ['lessThan', 'greaterThan', 'lessThanEqual', 'greaterThanEqual', 'equalTo', 'notEqualTo']
    };
```

In my css file:

```
/* Unicode icons for mathematical operators */
.lessThan:before {
  content: "\3c";
}
.greaterThan:before {
  content: "\3e";
}
.lessThanEqual:before {
  content: "\2264";
}
.greaterThanEqual:before {
  content: "\2265";
}
.equalTo:before {
  content: "=";
}
.notEqualTo:before {
  content: "\2260";
}

.popover_button span {
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  overflow:hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `popover-append-to-body`?

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: The six buttons appear all in a row using this method. Do you know how I would go about getting two rows of three buttons?

I'd imagine it involves using an ng-if in the ng-repeat that generates the buttons that does something after the third $index but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: `<br>` or `.col-sm-12` ?

Comment: br(ng-if="($index+1)%3==0") did the trick!

Comment: i think you can shorten it to `br(ng-if="!($index+1)%3")`, but it's still ugly :)